# Font Awesome is loading very slow

Tags: css

I have been doing some troubleshooting on my site, because the page load seemed very slow. I have icons on every page, multiple times as the site serves as a blog, and each blog post has share icons. By removing font awesome I noticed an extreme speed boost. Now I am unsure what to do because I need the icons. Any suggestions?

Update: 
I tried using my server and I also used CDN but I get the same results.

Comment: Are you loading FA off a CDN?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yes I am, I also tried loading from my server but same issue

Comment: What does your network request look like when you include FA cdn? And where are you loading this on your page?

Comment: @luke I get same results whether I load from CDN or from server. I am loading at the top of the page in the header

Comment: Try loading this in your header and see if it speeds it up. This will load FA asynchronously. Let me know the results.: `<script type="text/javascript">
 (function() {
  var css = document.createElement('link');
  css.href = '//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css';
  css.rel = 'stylesheet';
  css.type = 'text/css';
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(css);
 })();
</script>`

Comment: thanks will try this out

Comment: @luke yeah seems to work thanks alot

Comment: Added an answer to the question. Would appreciate marking it as correct :)  glad it works!

Comment: It is worth noting that Fontawesome's new Kits use JavaScript to fetch the CSS and are have async setting so you can load the CSS without blocking the page. The speed difference when Fontawesome is running slowly is huge with Kits being very fast.

Comment: FontAwesome adds a SVG element to every single element where you put the fa/fas style sheet. This can make the page very slow to load, especially if you use the symboles in tables with many rows.

Comment: Maybe, it could help others : have a look at [Friconix.com](https://friconix.com), you can select only the icons you need and upload the js file on your server, or even faster : inline JS code

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Load this into your head:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> (function() { var css = document.createElement('link'); css.href = 'https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css'; css.rel = 'stylesheet'; css.type = 'text/css'; document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(css); })(); </script>
```

What does this do exactly?
Well it loads font awesome via javascript which is placed at the head of the page. Basically we are rendering font awesome before rendering the page which means it should load quicker.

Comment: Would you mind sharing what this does over the default installation method?

Comment: It loads font awsome via javascript which placed at the head of the page blocks loading till run.

Back in older days scripts had to be at the bottom of the page to allow the page to render due to scripts blocking load. In this way we are loading the font before rendering the page.

Comment: I'd use the link referenced here instead to stay up to date with development: https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/fontawesome/

Comment: While using the original link provided in answer some of icons were not loading for me, specifically fa-education. Updating the link provided by @ThomasMondel worked like a charm

Comment: I updated to use the latest cdn

Comment: Why not just put `<link>` element in the header?

Comment: This is amazing. The speed boost is incredible. I was getting a flickering of an icon in a navbar everytime the page reloaded, regardless of whether the icons were saved locally or not, which is now completely indeterminable on all but a hard refresh.

Comment: @luke Although your solution helped to remove the delay I was experienced compared to the `<script crossorigin='anonymous' src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/ffa45bbbfe.js'/>` I had in my code, when I analyzed the page with PageSpeed Insights I got this new opportunity: `removed unused css: Remove dead rules from stylesheets and defer the loading of CSS not used for above-the-fold content to reduce unnecessary bytes consumed by network activity.` Do you have any idea why? I guess it hurts the score for me.

Answer (score 1):

Have to turned on the cache?
On an Apache Server you can add to your .htaccess:

```
 ExpiresActive On
 ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 month"
```

To get an overview about how to speed up your website you can test it at: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/